# Creating an SELINUX allow rule for sockets error with clamd

Tags: centos, squid, selinux, clamav

I've got a CentOS 7 box configured as a Squid proxy, with clamav and Squidclamav. Normally I would just disable SELINUX, but I am attempting to understand and setup allow rules properly. I've managed to create several to fix issues identified with squid however, one error related to sockets with clamd is causing problems.

> type=AVC msg=audit(1436899859.808:9282): avc:  denied  { unlink } for  pid=22802 comm="clamd" name="clamd.sock" dev="tmpfs" ino=729382 scontext=system_u:system_r:antivirus_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 tclass=sock_file

What module/allow rule do I need to fix this entry being reported in the audit.log?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting.html)?

Comment: Yes, I've been using audit2allow to build several custom policies. This is the one entry in my audit log that I cannot fix through any allow rule I generated

Comment: This should already be allowed. But that socket appears to be mislabeled. Have you applied the relevant updates? (i.e. to `selinux-policy*` packages) If so, delete `/var/run/clamd.sock` manually and restart the computer.

Comment: According to yum all packages are up to date

Comment: I don't have a sock at that locations instead I have /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock, as I have a clamd@scan.service in systemd.

Comment: Even those should be correctly labeled, but they aren't. Anything matching `/var/run/clamd.*` should be labeled `antivirus_var_run_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clamd socket file `/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock` has somehow gotten mislabeled. It has the type `var_run_t`, but it should be `antivirus_var_run_t` in current SELinux policy. Anything matching `/var/run/clamd.*` should be labeled `antivirus_var_run_t`.

This could be because the socket was created while an older version of the policy was installed, or a program or user could have manually mislabeled it.

Since you say the system is up to date, I would recommend relabeling the file (and, for that matter, the entire system, just to be sure), to correct any mislabeled files, and then restarting.

```
restorecon -r -v /
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to have fixed it! You are correct, I have did install clamd before applying the proper SELINUX rules for squid and such, so it looks like mislabelling is the issue here.